# Firebase - remote config on web sometimes gets values and sometimes not

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I'm new to programming in Javascript (I haven't even been programming for a month, but I have experience in other non-asynchronous languages).

I'm having trouble connecting the Firebase config to my website, sometimes it shows values, other times it doesn't.

`if (app_data) {
    console.log("Step 0");
    remoteConfig = getRemoteConfig(app_data);
    remoteConfig.settings.minimumFetchIntervalMillis = 10000;
  } else {
    console.log("No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos.");
  }

  if (fetchAndActivate(remoteConfig)) {
    console.log("Paso por 2");
    obj_config = getAll(remoteConfig);
    console.log("Paso por 3");
    Object.entries(obj_config).forEach((x) => {
      const [key, entry] = x;
      if (key === "contract_address") {
        contract_token = entry["_value"];
        console.log("Key Address: ", entry["_value"]);
      }
      console.log("Key: ", key);
      console.log("Source: ", entry.getSource());
      console.log("Value: ", JSON.stringify(entry["_value"]));
    });
    
  }`

If someone could help me, I would be very grateful.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

fetchAndActivate is async, so it won't have finished fetching yet:

instead of

```
if (fetchAndActivate(remoteConfig)) {
  //code
}
```

try

```
fetchAndActivate(remoteConfig).then(() => {
  // code
});
```

Comment: How do I get the contract_token variable out of that block? I need to use that variable to print it on this label:

<TokenBalance token_address={contract_token} balance_default="0" />

Comment: Does my example work to solve your initial question?

Comment: It could work if I didn't need to store a value in the contract_token variable inside the block, but I need to use that variable in a tag outside (the one I mentioned in the previous comment).

Comment: If you aren't able to use the value inside the .then function, and really need to return it, consider using async/await.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: I think I understand that the async/await functions also do not allow to return the value of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Javascript, you could try to use **await** in your code because the fetching step is asynchronous.
Something like

```
const rcResult = await asyncFetchFromRC()
```